# Geonode add new fields to pycsw

Tags: geonode, pycsw

I've added new fields to my base models. I would like it to reflect to my ISO metadata. Where do I start?

What fields can I place in my local_mappings? Can I add custom fields like purpose and abstract?

Answer (score 0):

You can add fields like purpose by updating GeoNode's [core ISO template](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/geonode/catalogue/templates/catalogue/full_metadata.xml%20core%20ISO%20template) which gets saved/updated whenever you update your fields in the edit metadata form.

GeoNode supports an abstract field already, so if you'd like to update where this is derived from the the metadata you can update the fieldname in [GeoNode's custom pycsw local mappings](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/geonode/catalogue/backends/pycsw_local_mappings.pyGeoNode's%20custom%20pycsw%20local%20mappings).

Comment: Hello tom, thanks for the answer, i have a similar case but with CKAN, i've changed my model to reflect the new fields, but it's not returned by the csw response, i would like to know what workflow should i follow and where should i make changes to get the results
thanks

Comment: In the GeoNode context, you also need to generate the XML (which gets stored) with the values generated from the new columns and when querying the CSW thereafter, always ask for `elementsetname=full` on CSW requests, which will provide the raw XML response of the document saved.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for the reply, definitly will try to check elementsetname=full,  please kindly check this out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448003/pycsw-retrieve-a-specific-fields-with-records
thanks again