# Pycsw retrieve a specific fields with records

Tags: qgis, csw, pycsw

I am integrating Pycsw with CKAN,

I am applying `sans1878` (south African standard) spec to the data, which makes a few more fields required than iso19135 needs to  as the purpose of the data.

I would like to retrieve these fields with the records within the search capability.

Currently, I am getting something as the following (copied from QGIS metadata search response), I have tried making a change to the apiso profile and added few fields to the csw:Record mapping to see if that reflects on the new fields, but without results. I am wondering about it all now.

Is this is the right direction (making new profiles)?

```
<csw:Record>

    <dc:identifier>057b8b79-af18-4ed7-a951-93dd0836a327</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title>sample-34</dc:title>
    <dc:type>http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/Dataset</dc:type>
    <dc:subject>Conservation</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject> geoscientificInformation</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject> sample-data</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject scheme="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#MD_TopicCategoryCode">geoscientificInformation</dc:subject>
    <dct:modified>2022-03-04T11:52:06Z</dct:modified>
    <dc:date>2022-05-09</dc:date>
    <dc:publisher>Nobody, No One, Ms.</dc:publisher>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <dct:alternative>samples-34</dct:alternative>
    <dct:spatial scheme="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs">EPSG:3857</dct:spatial>
    <ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.11:4326" dimensions="2">
        <ows:LowerCorner>-30.266752322825365 25.525308457506394</ows:LowerCorner>
        <ows:UpperCorner>-23.207908347527262 27.47071977739187</ows:UpperCorner>
    </ows:BoundingBox>
</csw:Record>
```

Comment: with the metadata search request the ElementSetName is full, the following shows with the request 
<csw:ElementSetName>full</csw:ElementSetName>

Comment: what profiles are shown to be offered in the CSW GetCapabilities response

Comment: thank you nmtoken for your feedback, should i take it that the profiles is what define the fields in the response ? 
it's the following profile 
<ows20:Profile>http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/apiso/1.0</ows20:Profile>